# Force all connected clients to update on next server request if needed

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

On my mostly one page website my menu gets its data once from a database when its not postback, to keep the server load down.

The items in the menu can be dynamically added to the menu by an admin on the admin side of the website.
but this makes every connected client have an outdated menu.

i want to know if:

- you're able to force all client to have somehow an update next server request when the admin said so?

i looked into asp.net SignalR but i dont think this is the way to do it, becouse this sounds heavy on the server side but i could be wrong?

Comment: SignalR sounds like the right way to do it.

Comment: Isnt SignalR heavy on the server? main reason for this is to keep the server load down

Comment: no its not, its just mostly a one page but not completly like the admin side.

Comment: @user2653652 Well I mean, there are certainly less load-intensive ways of doing it. Like, for instance, you could write an API and call it with AJAX every half hour. Everything you choose will be a trade-off between having something that works and having more load on the server. But realistically, SignalR is pretty good at what it does. I wouldn't worry about it from a load perspective unless you have to be extremely careful. And if you're running with those small of tolerances, there might be more that you need to rethink.

Comment: @Matthew Hauges i am gonna look more into SignalR Thanks for the help. if you make this as an answer i can sign it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was requested to post this as an answer. I'd probably go with SignalR.

- It's maintained by a team, so it tends to work likely better and more universally than something you or I throw together
- It's optimized for performance, and it's really good at what it does
- It's very scalable, which would be a hassle if you were to write something on your own.
- Regardless of its state now, it'll only get better. They have a code contract set up, and they'll continue to improve the engines behind it indefinitely, so your performance and coverage will theoretically, and if you update, just get better and better. It's their job to make it as good as it can be, so there's no use reinventing the wheel for something that you can only afford to look at now and then.

If you're really *that* worried about load, though, there are certainly less load-intensive ways of doing it.

You could, for instance, write an API and call it with AJAX every half hour, checking for changes. It'd be pretty straight-forward to write, but you'll still be waiting half an hour for data to be "pushed down," and you might find that the load of having all those clients call in at once is actually just as bad anyway.

Everything you choose will be a trade-off between having something that works and having more load on the server. But realistically, SignalR is pretty good at what it does. I wouldn't worry about it from a load perspective unless you have to be extremely careful. And if you're running with those small of tolerances, there might be more that you need to rethink.

Web servers are known for having peaks and valleys of use--day versus night, weekday versus weekend, rainy days versus sunny, so on and so forth. You want to make sure you've got enough to accommodate those users, and it sounds like if SignalR will bring you too close, you might not have enough.

I don't meant to tell you how to run your business, I'd just think twice if that is this much a concern.

Comment: Thanks, also for the large explanation.